# Background colour of TabBar is not changing using ESTabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

After changing the code as per POD documentation the background color of the TabBar is not changing.I am using ESTabBarController POD. Problem is in the third party itself. In these classes, you can change the background color of the Tabbar ExampleBasicContentView, ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView, ExampleIrregularityContentView

```
class ExampleBasicContentView: ESTabBarItemContentView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        textColor = UIColor.init(white: 175.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        highlightTextColor = UIColor.init(red: 254/255.0, green: 73/255.0, blue: 42/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        iconColor = UIColor.init(white: 175.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        highlightIconColor = UIColor.init(red: 254/255.0, green: 73/255.0, blue: 42/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


class ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView: ExampleBouncesContentView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        highlightTextColor = UIColor.init(red: 2/255.0, green: 152/255.0, blue: 212/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        iconColor = UIColor.lightGray
        highlightIconColor = UIColor.lightGray
        highlightIconColor = UIColor.init(red: 2/255.0, green: 152/255.0, blue: 212/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        backdropColor = UIColor.clear
        highlightBackdropColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: I am using ESTabBarController POD. Problem is in the third party itself.

Comment: Added the third party files code in which we have to write the code to change the background color as per our requirement.

Comment: there is no issue with a pod. I downloaded it and try changing the background. it's working for me for all cases

Comment: What rendering mode you are using to show the content view of ESTabBarItemContentView?

Comment: 3.3 Background color change style

Answer (score 0):

```
if let tabBar = esTabBarController.tabBar as? ESTabBar {
    tabBar.barTintColor = .desiredColor
}
```

past this after initialising ESTabBarController. [resource](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController/issues/110)